# Python-Instagram API example not working

Tags: python, instagram

I am looking to use the Python-Instagram package. I have downloaded the package using the script that is provided on https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram.

I have attempted one of the scripts that is provided. However, I get the same error: `ImportError: No module named client`

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
     print media.caption.text
```

What is the module client and how can I install it? I have registered a client with IG.

Answer (score 10):

Did you put the name "instagram" on the file? This might be your problem.

After seeing this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/lfP-RAn2H9s), which describes the same error, I realized my mistake.

Comment: Very same thing happened to me. You should delete all files named "instagram", including the invisibles  instagram.py~ and instagram.pyc~

Answer (score 3):

I just had this same problem and it turned out that I had file named instagram.py in the same package as the file where I was getting this error. So, it was just a name collision. I renamed my local file and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

### The recommended way:

1. Make sure you have [pip installed](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)
2. Install the package with the command: `pip install python-instagram` (you may require administrator/sudo privileges for this)

### Manual Installation:

1. Download the zip file from https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram
2. Copy the `instagram` directory to your python's `dist-package` directory or `site-package` directory (whatever is relevant to you)

You should then be able to import InstagramAPI with

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
```

Comment: Pip or python instagram? Which is not working? Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry to not be clear.  I did use pip install python-instagram.  It installed correctly.  I am using a Mac OS X 10.9.5

Comment: I am in ubuntu but this should be the same for Mac OS X: `import instagram` then `dir(instagram)` should list `['InstagramAPI', 'InstagramAPIError', 'InstagramClientError', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'bind', 'client', 'helper', 'json_import', 'models', 'oauth2']`. Do you find anything missing?

Answer (score 2):

You may end up here like I did, and even by having

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
```

and everything else correctly set I still got the error:

```
ImportError: No module named InstagramAPI
```

I was stupid enough to have InstagramAPI installed in one venv and was using another venv to run my project... dah