# python-instagram example (404) Unable to parse response, not valid JSON

Tags: python, json, instagram-api

Here is a example for [instagram](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram#using-an-access-token) that does not work. 
I have found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288687/python-instagram-api-example-not-working) but it does not solve my problem, python-instagram is installed and file name is ok. where is the problem?

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
api = InstagramAPI(client_id='xxx',
               client_secret='xxx')
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
```

problem is with api.media_popular .

error:

```
raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.',
status_code=response['status'])
InstagramClientError: (404) Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.
```

Comment: The example youve shown is old. Possibly things have changed and the response coming back from your query isnt valid json. You should check out the [instagram developer documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from [python-instagram lib readme](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram):

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
   print media.caption.text
```

And popular_media:

```
api.media_popular(count, max_id)
```

More info is here om the "Libraries" tab: https://www.instagram.com/developer/libraries/

Comment: dose not work, error =>   raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.', status_code=response['status'])
InstagramClientError: (404) Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.

Comment: Ok. And what if you place breakpoint here? https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/blob/dfeebe91cf389017e1786bd153d3d1285406ee9e/instagram/bind.py#L126 What is the value of `conent` variable?