# Python-Instagram API example not working v2

Tags: python, instagram-api

I am trying to use the Python-Instagram API as described here: https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram

On the first step however, I get the error message:

```
    File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
        from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
ImportError: No module named instagram.client
```

I read in this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288687/python-instagram-api-example-not-working) that this error has occurred and described before, however none of the solutions helped me.

1. OS: Kali Linux
2. I ran the following command `pip install python-instagram` and it installed successfully
3. I have copied the the instagram directory (after unpacking the git's source .zip file) to my python's `dist-package` directory or site-package directory (whatever is relevant to you)
4. The main.py is in a folder on my Desktop (if this matters)
5. I have installed python 2.7.13

Still nothing works. My questions are (besides the obvious of how to fix the error)

1. What should be the name of my program (.py)
2. Should I copy / past the instagram folder from the git .zip to the python folder?
3. Where should I be running my program from?
4. Finally, how can the `import InstagramAPI` work?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288687/python-instagram-api-example-not-working

Comment: I did (and have it as a link on my question, but nothing from there helped me)

Comment: Did you name your file as instagram

Comment: Why did you do that third step? You should not have done that.

Comment: @Wboy I did it now and I still get the same error (see updated question)

Comment: I thought these were the instruction in the previous question. That's why I did it @DanielRoseman

Comment: rename your file to main.py and do python main.py

Comment: No that's not what that answer says at all. That is an alternative to pip, but to be honest you should always just use pip.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't read well. Your program is called main.py so it should be correct. Maybe you have some instagram.py around?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by your comment/question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry again. As suggested in the link you posted it seems that, maybe, you have some instagram.py which does not contain the adequate code (maybe some test from you or something like htat). Python sees it instead of the one you installed and this is the reason it does not work. So, you called your file main.py, and this is ok. But if there exists a file called instagram.py, this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the traceback, it appears you are doing

```
python instagram.py
```

rename the file to `main.py` (or simply something other than `instagram.py`) and do

```
python main.py
```

The reason that it doesn't work for you is that your main script imports itself, rather than the actual Instagram module.

---

*Update* -- The error message you are getting now is a different one. It says that there is no `instagram` module, which is right if there is no longer an `instagram.py` file *and* if you didn't install the actual module.

Step 3. should not have been necessary when installing `python-instagram`. Did `pip install python-instagram` finish successfully? Could it be you have multiple Python installations and the `pip` command refers to Pip from a different Python version than the `python` command?

Comment: Hi, I did this (and this is how my original script actually was), however I am getting the same error.

Comment: From your updated question, I can see that you're not getting the *same* error. The message is a different one.

Comment: After `pip install python-instagram` I received four commands of `Requirement already satisfied`: that is for `python-instagram`, `six`, `simplejson`, `httplib2`. However when running `python main.py` again I get the same error.

Comment: Sounds like `pip` is installing to a different Python version than what you're using to run your script. What does `python --version` and `pip --version` give?

Comment: For `python --version` I get `Python 2.7.13`.
For `pip --version`  I get `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)` I am not sure by this, if they are the same (compatible) versions.